# What is the fixed point of fix?

Tags: haskell, recursion, fixpoint-combinators

A recent poster best left anonymous attempted to implement the factorial function like this:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f = fix f
```

This obviously didn't work out too well. But then I got to wondering: can I make it pass the type checker? What will its type reveal?

Comment: wow ... I did not get the part with `fact` ^^ - but thanks for the update

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, it will type check given a more general type, thanks to polymorphic recursion:

```
f :: a
f = fix f
```

By parametricity, we can immediately see that it must be bottom, and based on the definition of `fix`, it must be an infinite loop rather than an exception.

chi [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555893/what-is-the-fixed-point-of-fix/35555938?noredirect=1#comment58800743_35555938), "For the same reason `f = bar f` will 'work' with any `bar :: F a -> a` where `F a` is any type (which may depend on `a`)". The definition looks like this:

```
foo :: forall f a .
       (forall b . f b -> b) -> a
foo g = g (foo g)
```

Again, the type signature is bogus by parametricity, since I can choose, for example, `f ~ Const Void`, at which point it is clear that the first argument is useless for producing the result.

Comment: Interesting. For the same reason `f = bar f` will "work" with any `bar :: F a -> a` where `F a` is any type (which may depend on `a`). E.g. `proj2 :: (a,a) -> a`. I actually think there's nothing special about `fix` which is being exploited here.

Comment: Regarding `fix`, these also type check: `f3 :: a -> a ; f3 = fix f3` and `f4 :: (a -> a) -> a -> a ; f4 = fix f4`. Polymorphic recursion is still needed (of course!), but I find it interesting that we have more typings than `::a` (infinitely many, I presume).

Comment: @chi, see my edit responding to your first comment. Your second is valid as well, but because Haskell's evil `seq` can distinguish among `⊥`, `const ⊥`, `const (const ⊥)`, etc., the most general `forall a . a` typing is also the most informative.

Comment: What do you mean by parametricity in the answer ? I cannot immediately see that it is a bottom from parametricity.

Comment: @Sibi, something with type `forall a . a` must be able to produce something of type `a` for any `a`, without any information about `a`. This is impossible, but for ⊥.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That makes it clear. Probably adding `forall` to the function `f` will make it easier.